# zipline: Runtime figuring out what assets/symbols are provided by a bundle?

Tags: zipline

Apologies if this has an obvious solution, but I find the API documentation of zipline quite lacking with lots of holes.

Either in the `initialize(context)` function or the `handle_data(context, data)` function, is there an easy way to get a list of all the symbols in the asset universe?

E.g. if I have a custom bundle made of a bunch of tickers from yahoo, I can't seem to find something as easy as `context.get_all_assets()` or so. It seems I always have to manually provide a list of symbols so that I can set, e.g. `context.assets = symbols('AAPL', 'SNAP', 'FB')`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this. I found this by using pdb to go through the logic.

```
def initialize(context):
    context.i = 0
    assets = context.asset_finder.sids #something like this
    assert len(assets) >= 1
    context.asset = context.sid(assets[0])
```